# Simple uniform hashing assumption

Tags: hash

In several proofs of the expected lookup length in an open addressing hash table, an assumption is made (which is said to follow from the "simple uniform hashing assumption":

> Given a hash table with n slots and m keys in it, the probability that any particular slot is occupied is m/n.

I can't figure out how this follows. I mean how do you structure an experiment, that is, what is the sample space and how do you calculate this.

I'm thinking of a sample space consisting of m-tuples of keys. The experiment is to randomly select one such tuple. The event A is the set of all such tuples that have at least 1 key in them that hashes into the given slot.

The probability of A then is `1 - (the probability that none of the m keys hash to the given slot)`. So `1 - ((n-1)/n)^m`. But that's not equal to `m/n`...

Comment: This might get better answers on the sister site https://cs.stackexchange.com/ as it is more about the theory than any practical problem. Your question is also a bit confusing because you haven't explained where _your_ calculation of the probability comes from, so it's hard to see if you've made a wrong assumption to get there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)